# Trace minimization when some matrix is unknown

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

The problem is as follows:
$\displaystyle\min_{V}$ trace(**$V^TH^T\Phi HV$**)$\\$ s.t. $V^TV=I_d$ in the case when $H$ is not known.

When $H$ is known, the solution is given by the eigenvectors corresponding to $d$ minimum eigenvalues of $ H^T\Phi H$.

Is there anyway to solve the problem in the absence of $H$? $H$ is a full column rank matrix. $\Phi$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

I hope to receive the suggestions if there are any. Or is there any technique that I can rephrase the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please specify the dimensions of the matrices above.

Comment: The dimensions are as follows: $V \in M \times d, M \ge d$, $H \in N \times M, N \ge M$ and $\Phi \in N \times N$

Comment: @jpara usually it is preferable to use similar notations for same class of parameters, variables, ... Here you used non-capital $d$ for a scalar parameter so why not $m$ and $n$ instead of $M$ and $N$? also you used capital letters for matrices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trace minimization-Revised](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266509/trace-minimization-revised)