# Trace minimization-Revised

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

The problem is as follows:
$\displaystyle\min_{V}$ trace(**$V^TH^T\Phi HV$**)$\\$ s.t. $V^TV=I_d$ in the case when $H$ is not known.

When $H$ is known, the solution is given by the eigenvectors corresponding to $d$ minimum eigenvalues of $ H^T\Phi H$.

Is there anyway to solve the problem in the absence of $H$? $H$ is a full column rank matrix. $\Phi$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

I hope to receive the suggestions if there are any. Or is there any technique that I can rephrase the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your objective function doesn't depend on your variable $V$ because we have : $\mbox{Trace}(AB)=\mbox{Trace}(BA)$ so in your problem we have :
$\mbox{Trace}(V^TH^TQHV)=\mbox{Trace}(H^TQHVV^T)=\mbox{Trace}(H^TQHI)=\mbox{Trace}(H^TQH)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You can use MathJax to format mathematics in a better way on this site. I took the liberty of doing that for you this time, but consider reading about MathJax on this site in the help center.

Comment: Note that $V^TV = I_d$, while you used the unassumed statement $VV^T=I_d$. Therefore we cannot say that this problem does not depend on $V$. It will in most cases.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to mention the dimensions. Following are the dimensions of the terms used $H \in N \times M, N \ge M$, $V \in M \times d, M > d$ and $\Phi \in N \times N$. So $VV^T \ne I_d$ even though $V^TV=I_d$.